# XAML Image Source isn't showing up

Tags: xml, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, powershell

I am **new** to Visual Studio and haven't had much luck with getting the image to appear correctly. This XAML file code is used in powershell to generate a window that is used in a task sequence.

Here is the code I've tried with the image being in the same folder as the XAML file. It doesn't work. The background just stays white in VS and it errors out in PowerShell:

```
<Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Background.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
```

But if I specify the **EXACT** location using a full path, then it works fine and works in PowerShell fine. Any help would be appreciated.

**I need it to look for the image in the root folder.**

Comment: **UPDATE**

I added an image folder inside my project and added the image in there. Made it a resource. Works in Visual studio, but throws an error in powershell.

Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text 'Images/YRC.jpg'."

I created an images folder inside where the script is.. but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: other example on the net are using complete path...https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/16/part-ii-deploying-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio/  can't tell more

Comment: I feel like the issue could be caused by this "Grid"

'code  <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/YRC.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>

That's the current code piece for the MainGrid, which is where the background needs to be. It works fine in Visual Studio, but errors out in Powershell.

Comment: powershel is different, it can load the xaml from a single string....and it has no assembly/exe context i am sure you can change to "c:\images" or "http:\\web\myimage" and it works...relative can't be resolved without context

Answer (score 0):

hmmm try to do something like this... if this still doesn't work, add the border before the grid

```
<Grid >
        <Image Source="Images/background_top.png"  Grid.RowSpan="3" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="Label" Grid.Row="0" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="testing here" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```